# Javascript addEventListener function gets invoked without the Event being triggered

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, addeventlistener

I may be overlooking something obvious but this just doesn't seem to go right.

I have this little code block in which an `addEventListener` method should trigger a function and meanwhile pass a parameter through so I can work with different functions while creating all `EventListeners` with one loop.
It does work, but the function gets invoked immediately when the site finishes loading.

Why doesn't the function wait until it gets triggered, but runs immediately?

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html');
var pics = document.getElementsByClassName('pics');
var functions = [];

for(h=0;h<pics.length;h++){
    array[h] = show(h);
}

for(p=0;p<pics.length;p++){
    pics[p].addEventListener('click',array[p]);
}

function show(index){
    html[0].style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
```

Comment: `array[h] = show(h);` this executes `show(h)` and stores the return value in `array[h]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the script

```
for (h = 0; h < pics.length; h++) {
    array[h] = show(h);
  }
```

you are calling the function `show` with value of h.

Its invoked at that time.So,background get setup with given color.

Its not because of `addEventListener` you are adding in the second `for loop`

You can write in this way.

```
for (h = 0; h < pics.length; h++) {
    array[h] = show; // don't  call,store the function reference
  }

  for (p = 0; p < pics.length; p++) {
    pics[p].addEventListener('click', array[p].bind(this,p));
  }
```

You can shorten two for loop into one

```
  for (p = 0; p < pics.length; p++) {
    pics[p].addEventListener('click', show.bind(this,p));
  }
```

Note :

[`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) expect `callback` and not an `function call`.

Comment: It works, thanks for your help! could you explain the .bind method to me in some easy words? i dont quite get how it works, even after researching it on the Internet. greetz!

Answer (score 0):

`array[h] = show(h);` is being invoked on page load. Here is working code.

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html');
var pics = document.getElementsByClassName('pics');
var functions = [];
var array = [];

for(h=0;h<pics.length;h++){
  array[h] = function () { show(h) };
}

for(p=0;p<pics.length;p++){
  pics[p].addEventListener('click',array[p]);
}

function show(index){
  html[0].style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
```